# Can we update the variables that are manipulated by NSTimer?

Tags: objective-c, timer, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer

I am using `NSTimer` that updates 2 different values `secondsLeft` and `totalSecondsLeft`. I don't have to change `secondsLeft` but I have to add more seconds to `totalSecondsLeft` when an action is performed.

Whenever I assign a value to `totalSecondsLeft` the `timer` still updating and printing the previous value. I saw different solutions and tried invalidating the timer and start it again after updating the `totalSecondsLeft` value but not working.

So I ended up creating 2 different instances of the `timer` with same variables but printing different values i.e, `secondsLeft` is same in both cases but `totalSecondsLeft` is different in both cases.

I tried many solutions and added `timer` instance to `GCD main_queue` using functions and invalidating the timer from the same queue still not getting working solution.

Here is my code:

```
[self settime];

-(void)settime
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
          timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(Countdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    });
}


-(void) Countdown
{   
    secondsLeft=secondsLeft-1;
    totalSecondsLeft=totalSecondsLeft-1;
    NSLog(@"secondsLeft : %i and totalSecondsLeft : %i",secondsLeft,totalSecondsLeft);
}


-(void)otherMethod
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
       timer=nil;
       [timer invalidate];
    });
   [self settime];
}
```

Help me to figure out. Thanks in advance

Comment: I first call settime, it calls timer, it calls countdown. I call the otherMethod after I met some condition while the timer is still running.

Comment: I have to give a new value to totalSecondsLeft in otherMethod which is not getting reflected in the timer that is already running. So I tried invalidating it and start the timer again with updated values but it is not getting invalidated. Now I have 2 timers running at the same time with different values